# Page redirect does not work on click event in jQuery

Tags: jquery, redirect, click

When I try redirect page after click a link, functions are not working that placed under click event. Because when I click, the page is immediately redirect without waiting perform tasks. My codes are here:

```
var site = 'http://www.sitename.com';    
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#messages').on('click', '.read', function () {

          $.cookie("show_messages", "false", { expires: 120, path: '/' });

          $('body').fadeOut(1000, function () {
              window.location.href = site + "/home-page";
          });
          return false;
        });
    });
```

I want to set a cookie than redirect page but I did not manage it. Could you help me? Kind regards...

Comment: code shown should set cookie long before redirect. Sounds like you have other errors being thrown and blocking your code. Check console. WHere is `site` defined?

Comment: @charlietfl - site value have remained above.

Comment: So no errors in console? Does `#messages` exist on page load? Is `read` the proper class? There is nothing wrong with the code shown so problem is elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a problem in your click function, and because of that it never gets to the `return false;` statement. I tried to reproduce your code in jsFiddle and for me it breaks on `$.cookie`, are you sure you have included a plugin that supports that method? It's not part of jQuery.

To prevent problems like this, cancel your event first and *then* proceed to your code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#messages').on('click', '.read', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.cookie("show_messages", "false", { expires: 120, path: '/' });

        $('body').fadeOut(1000, function () {
            window.location.href = site + "/home-page";
        });
    });
});
```

With `event.preventDefault()` you prevent the click event without having to `return` anything.

Comment: I am using Cookie Plug-in (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). But when I get window.location.href into comment tag, cookie is set.

Comment: Are `event.preventDefault()` and `return false` same things? Both of them did not slove the problem.